# extrar informacion y colocarlo en una tabla con una funcion PHP

Tags: php

hola buenas necesito realizar una tabla con informacion de una base de datos usando funciones que aparecen en el codigo cololarlos en una tabla a esto hacerle un bucle para que se se vallan agregando datos nuevos este es mas o menos el codigo que tengo me dijieron q usara un WHILE pero no me esta funcionando al llamar al objeto y dandonde una variable........................................................................................................................

```
<?php

class MysqliDb {

private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "root";
private $pass = "";
private $dbname = "alumnos";

private $connection;

function __construct()
{       
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(           
        $this->host,
        $this->user,
        $this->pass,
        $this->dbname
    );
    $this->connection->set_charset("utf8");
}
function executeQuery($sql){
    $data = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            array_push($data, $row);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

function numRows($sql){
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
    return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}

$db = new MysqliDb();
?>
<html>
<table border=1 align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>nombre</td>
        <td>apellido</td>
        <td>idCarrera</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $num = $db->numRows("SELECT * FROM `alumno`");
        while(.......){

            $id= $num ["id"];
            $nom= $num ["nombre"];
            $ape= $num ["apellido"];
            $idcar= $num ["idCarrera"]
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $id; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $nom; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $ape; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $idcar; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php

        }
        ?>
</table>
</html>
<?php
```

Comment: Perdona, pero tienes el código muy descuidado. No cierras la clase antes de intentar usarla, intentas iterar $num que no es un executeQuery, sino un simple número, no abres la tabla que luego cierras al final, usas while cuando lo suyo en este caso, dado que executeQuery te devuelve un array, es usar foreach().  Corrige todo eso, hazlo funcionar sin errores, y si aún así no te sale edita la pregunta con lo que has intentado y que te muestra el error (pues ahora mismo hay demasiados y no se ejecuta de ninguna forma)

Comment: gracias si, tuve q recortar el codigo porque no me dejaba hacer la pregunta edite el codigo un poco para ver si se entendia mejor, tratare de formular mejor la pregunta.

Comment: La pregunta se entiende, pero sigue con el resto de errores que te he dicho en mi anterior comentario.  Revisalo bien. Tal como lo tienes ahora seguro que ni se ejecuta nada, y algunos son errores de sintaxis básicos (no cerrar una clase antes de usarla) y otros de concepto (no saber lo que es $num ni como usar el while)

Comment: cuando hago la consulta solo me arroja esta linea 
 <table border=1 align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>nombre</td>
        <td>apellido</td>
        <td>idCarrera</td>
    </tr>
esta linea de codigo

Comment: Ves paso a paso, venga, sino no terminarás nunca... 1) Cierra la clase agregando una llave de cierre `}` antes de esta línea: `$db = new MysqliDb();`

Comment: Y luego quita estas lineas: `$num = $db->numRows("SELECT * FROM `alumno`"); while(.......){` y pon esto en su lugar: `$items = $db->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM \`alumno\`"); foreach($items as $num) {` y prueba de nuevo a ver que sucede

Comment: ooo DIOS funcionoo era un foreach muchas gracias !!!!!!!

Comment: He agregado la respuesta con un poco de explicación. Sírvete aceptarla para que la comunidad sepa que ha sido solucionada, gracias. En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo (para no dejar las preguntas eternamente pendientes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución pasa por cerrar primero la clase (error tipográfico) agregando un cierre de llave `}` antes de esta línea:

```
$db = new MysqliDb();
```

y después cambiar esto:

```
$num = $db->numRows("SELECT * FROM `alumno`");
while(.......){
```

por esto:

```
$items = $db->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `alumno`");
foreach($items as $num) {
```

pues el **numRows()** de esa clase poco nos importa para recorrer los datos, es más cómodo con un **foreach()** aprovechando que el método **executeQuery()** de la clase nos devuelve un array con los datos.